# React deployment/running options

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot REST backend which i need to use from a React front-end. I dont have any React experience so what i need to know is the requirements of React front-end deployment.

1. Is it possible to run React with good old standart web hosting options (like we are serving static sites)?
2. Is it mandatory to install NodeJS in the server?
3. Other than NodeJS are there any other minimum mandatory requirements for React front-end to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can just `build` your react app and host it as static content with nginx or any other server. You don't need node.js

Comment: Unless you need Server-side rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, build and then upload the files.
2. No
3. A modern web browser ?

Comment: Thanks for the "A modern web browser" answer :)